# Why can't I click() links in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, onclick, jquery, mouseclick-event

I came across a curiosity in jQuery: if I call `.click()` on a link the `click` event handlers are called, but the link isn't actually followed (as if it were clicked in the browser):

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com>Link</a>

$("#link").click() // won't take me to Google
```

But in plain Javascript, everything behaves as expected:

```
document.getElementById("link").click() // *will* take me to Google
```

This is apparently [intentional behaviour](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L363) - but I'm struggling to work out why `click` was implemented like this - with a special exception for links?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9a6sp/

To clarify: I'm not asking how to click link in JS, but rather, why the default behaviour in jQuery is effectively that links *aren't clicked* when you call `.click()`

Comment: The native `.click()` is IE-only.

Comment: @Smamatti: `.click()`is shorthand for that.

Comment: No. That doesn't work either - but I'm not really trying to understand how to make this work, but rather why this doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexPeattie That's not really what your question says...

Comment: @AlexPeattie To trigger a link's navigation from JS, you can use the venerated `window.location.href = $('#link')[0].attr('href')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`domelement.click()` isn't supported cross browser for redirecting. If you need to redirect to the location in a link you can use:

```
window.location = $('#link').prop('href');
```

Comment: In fact, the `click()` method doesn't even exist on native anchor elements in Chrome, so it's not supported for anything.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is meant to bind a click handler to an element. However it can be used to trigger a click() event bound using jQuery.

[jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) will trigger a bound event handler, such as `$(someElement).trigger("click");`

If you wanted to trigger a link in jQuery may I suggest the following.

```
$(someelement).click(function () {
  window.location = $(link).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: The ".click()" with no arguments is exactly the same as calling ".trigger('click')".

Comment: @Pointy.  didnt I say that in my second sentence?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to clarify exactly that but I apparently failed :-)

Comment: The only issue I'd have with this explanation is that `submit()` will trigger events bound using jQuery *and* trigger the default browser behavior (submitting the form).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?
First, you need to attach a click event.
then you can use trigger to fire it.

```
<html>
<head title="jQuery Test">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#blah').click(function () {
                alert('clicked');
            });
            $('#blah').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="blah" href="#">BLAH</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For why this isn't work, in jsFiddle `$('#link')` doesn't select the anchor in html, and `click()` fails. Even the type selector `$('a').href` fails.

http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/L9EUS/

The code works in normal browser. I have tested the code on stackoverflow.com with this code
`jQuery('a').eq(1).click()` in chrome concole, it triggers the `click()` on the logo.

So **in conclusion**, click() links work in jQuery(). jsfiddle.net has interrupts the normal jQuery function.

Comment: Your fiddle fails because you have to call $('a').attr("href") instead.
Call $('a').size() to check if anything is found.
Sadly this makes your conclusion incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just guessing as to **why** the jQuery team chose to implement things this way, since I'm not on the jQuery team, but the navigation aspect of an anchor tag can be triggered by other UI behaviors than just clicking with the mouse.  For example in plain old javascript, using the keyboard to activate an element doesn't trigger the onClick action, but it *will* trigger the navigation action of an anchor tag.

In other words, by clicking on a link you're just using one of several possible mechanisms for navigating to the referenced endpoint, but the navigation and the click aren't the same event, so jQuery chose to treat the click just that.